# {"<nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied."}

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

Can anyone help me in below issue?

My code below, is trying to access a document library from a site collection.
At a below line (SPFolder docLibrary = oweb.Folders[strOriginalDocLibName];) its giving me an error like, {"0x80070005Access denied."}.

Can anyone let me know what is causing this error?
and if anyone has a solution to it?

its on my local environment and I have full control over the site collection.

> public static void FunctionMetadataUpdation(string strSiteUrl, string
>   strDocLibName, string strFuncName)
>           {
>
> ```
>         try
>         {
>             Logging.InsertLog("In FunctionMetadataUpdation function ", false, strFuncName);
>             #region Updating Metadata for all the Functions of PT
>
>
>             using ( SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strSiteUrl))
>             {
>
>                 using (SPWeb oweb = oSite.OpenWeb())
>                 {
>                     string strOriginalDocLibName = "";
>                     if (strFuncName.Equals("PM"))
>                     {
>
>                         strOriginalDocLibName = "Program Management";
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         strOriginalDocLibName = strDocLibName;
>                     }
>
>                         ***SPFolder docLibrary = oweb.Folders[strOriginalDocLibName];***                        
>                         SPList lst = oweb.Lists[strDocLibName];                       
>
>                     try
>                     {
>                         foreach (SPFolder folder in docLibrary.SubFolders)
>                         {
> ```

Comment: Have you tried running the code as elevated?

Comment: Thanks... it worked.
I was not knowing how to use elevated function. I googled it and applied.